# How can I update a MySQL record with foreign key in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pdo, crud

Im trying to update a record in MySQL using PHP. The record has 2 foreign keys, member_type and financial_year. Now I use the code below:

```
    public function update($pdo)
    {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE contribution SET age=? member_type=(SELECT id FROM member_type WHERE id=?) amount=? financial_year=(SELECT id FROM financial_year WHERE id=?) WHERE id=?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->age, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $this->memberType->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $this->amount, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);
        $stmt->bindParam(4, $this->financialYear->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(5, $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        
        $stmt->execute([$this->age, $this->memberType->id, $this->amount, $this->financialYear->id, $this->id]);
```

But when I run this, I get an error message saying there is an error in my query.

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong here?
In any case, thanks for thinking along!

I have trying te SELECT id FROM member_type WHERE id=?. Before this I used member_type=? where I used the $this->memberType->id for the questionmark.

Comment: You forgot to add *what particular error you get*.

Comment: You need commas between each of the things you are trying to SET

Comment: (Also, no need to pass the parameters twice - either use `bindParam` or pass them in the array to `execute()`, but don't do both)

Comment: Please could you clarify why you are using subselects that return the same value?  eg `member_type=(SELECT id FROM member_type WHERE id=?)` - is this some kind of validation check on member_type?  It might be easier just to specify a foreign key constraint on the table, then you could just do `member_type=?` and let the MySQL server do the integrity check for you